# Generalized Linear Model without factor?

Tags: generalized-linear-model

I have a dataset with one dependent (continuous) variable that is not normally distributed and three independent (continuous) variables.I would like to run GLM with one dependent variables against three independent variables. Can I run a GLM without factor (categorical variable) as an independent variable?

Comment: The question is not clear to me. You already mentioned that you've three continuous variable, where does the last factor variable come from?

Comment: Yes, the problem is that I have no factor variable. Therefore, I asked whether I should run a GLM with my current dataset.

Comment: OK. What kind of response variable are you dealing with? You already mentioned that it's not normally distributed.

Comment: Response variable is frequency or count variable. So, I choose a log link function as the response variable should follow poisson distribution. Thanks indeed.

Comment: f frequency, then you need to use either Poisson or Negative Binomial (check for over dispersion) distribution with a log link function.

Comment: It would be helpful to explain why you doubt that a GLM might be appropriate without any categorical variable as a predictor.

Answer (score 3):

Absolutely, you'll want to run a GLM based on a Gaussian distribution for continuous data (For count data you want to use a Poisson distribution). For a Gaussian (normal) distribution it doesn't matters if your continuous variable is not normally distributed. The assumption is the **errors** from the model are normally distributed. GLM covers regression methods for many types of data: continuous, count, categorical, binomial etc. The important part is that you select the right distribution type for the link function.

See here for more details:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_linear_model

Comment: Thank you for your answer. My question does not mean to normal or non-normal distribution of the data. It just means to that should I run a GLM without a factor as independent (not meaning dependent) variable.

Comment: His response variable is not normally distributed.

Comment: That's not an issue. Yes you don't need categorical variables to run a GLM regression. Just make sure you select the right distribution according to your dependent variable.

Answer (score 0):

Running a GLM without a factor is not a problem at all. Infact LMs, on which GLMs are based, are regression models original developed without factors in mind.